# При сравнение с помощью equals результат false

Tags: java

Считываю текст из файла и разделение переменных идет с помощью буквы W.
Создаю простое условие

```
if(result.equals("W"))
```

и раз через раз он выдает на знак W `false`
(*проверял через дебагер, что точно W*).

Единственное, что я заметил в дебагере у переменной значение `coder = 1`, когда `true` то `0`. 
Но я не понимаю от чего это зависит и что означает. 
Тип документа UTF 8; 
Считываю с помощью сканера

Comment: Из вопроса не cовсем ясно, что такое переменная `coder`, приведите код. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки ["править"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1459429/edit).

Comment: `coder` - это кодировка строки (для хранения побайтовов или посимвольно) внутри `String`. Если в строке реально только один символ `W` , то `coder` и будет равен `0` (`LATIN1`).

Comment: @kzrvv Дебаггер может шалить и показывать не совсем правильные вещи (например, сталкивался с таким во время разработки под андроид). Попробуйте подебажить старым добрым способом через `println` :) Результат будет такой же? Приведите код и создайте [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), который будет демонстрировать проблему.

Comment: У текста из файла есть символ переноса строки (пробел). и на самом деле ваше W может быть с невидимым символом

Comment: Покажите отрывок из вашего файла

Comment: Всем спасибо, воспользовался println, и действительно был пробел, который в дебагере не показывался)